# Optimization with Loop Tiling and OpenMP

Tags: c, optimization, openmp

Below is my function that I'm trying to optimize using OpenMP and Loop Tiling(aka Loop Blocking). However, my output of out currently gives the wrong value after I apply the loop tiling like below. Can someone look over my code, and point out what makes it wrong. Thank you so much

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <omp.h>
#include "utils.h"
const long BLOCK_SIZE = 8*DIM;
int i, j, k,ii,jj,kk, dim = DIM-1;

long compute, out = 1.0, we_need, gimmie;

void work_it_par(long *old, long *new)
{
 we_need = need_func();
 gimmie = gimmie_func();

 #pragma omp parallel for private(i,j,k,ii,jj,kk, compute)      firstprivate(we_need, gimmie, dim,old,BLOCK_SIZE) reduction(+:out)   num_threads(omp_get_num_procs())
for (ii=1; ii<dim-BLOCK_SIZE; ii+=BLOCK_SIZE) {
  for (jj=1; jj<dim-BLOCK_SIZE; jj+=BLOCK_SIZE) {
    for (kk=1; kk<dim-BLOCK_SIZE; kk+=BLOCK_SIZE) {
      for (i=ii; i<ii+BLOCK_SIZE; i++) {
        for (j=jj; j<jj+BLOCK_SIZE; j++) {
          for (k=kk; k<kk+BLOCK_SIZE; k++) {
            //int temp = i*DIM*DIM+j*DIM+k;
            compute = old[i*DIM*DIM+j*DIM+k] * we_need;
            out += compute / gimmie;
          }
        }
      }

    }
  }
}

printf("AGGR:%ld\n",out);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, `const long BLOCK_SIZE = 8*DIM;` seems super fishy to me...
Maybe replacing the `*` by a `/` would be more of what you wanted?

But even though, you still have to deal with the limits by checking that the `i`, `j` and `k` indexes do not go over their limits. I let you figure out how to achieve that.

Last point on the algorithm: are you sure your loops have to start from index 1?

Finally, a few notes on the OpenMP correctness:

- although I see nothing wrong in there, declaring `firstprivate(we_need, gimmie, dim,old,BLOCK_SIZE)` doesn't make much sense. These could happily stay `shared`.
- I don't really know whether `num_threads(omp_get_num_procs())` is correct or not. My feeling is that it is indeed valid, but just for "safety", I would tend to separate the call to the function from the directive (by either calling the function first and storing its result in a constant, and using it in the directive, or calling `omp_set_num_threads()`before the `parallel` directive)
- when your algorithm is fixed, you might want to consider adding some `collapse` directive to increase the level of parallelism you achieve here...

Good luck with your code.

Comment: `num_threads(omp_get_num_procs())` is not needed, it's kind of the default anyways.  If no `num_threads` clause is present or the number of threads is change through the environment or the API, OpenMP will usually use all the cores available (although this is implementation-defined).

Comment: @MichaelKlemm I agree setting the number of threads to the maximum of available processing cores is kind of redundant with the default in most cases (although it is implementation defined), and maybe when it is not, that might be for a reason. So forcing it, which prevents the user to subsequently adjust that with `OMP_NUM_THREADS` is probably a bad idea. But my point was more about the call to a run-time function inside a compile-time directive: I think (hope) it is valid but I still prefer avoiding it just in case...

Comment: You can have (almost) arbitrary code in OpenMP clauses that take an expression. OpenMP defines when these expressions are evaluated. As usual: with great power comes great responsibility. :-)